# Setting before rendering html page go-gin

Tags: cookies, go

I am trying to set a cookie on an HTML page

```
 func testCookie(c *gin.Context) {
    c.SetCookie("test1", "testvalue", 10, "/", "", true, true)
    c.HTML(200, "dashboard", gin.H{
        "title":    "Dashboard",
        }
    }
```

This should have set the cookie on the HTML page but it doesn't.
My server is running to serve https requests. I am not sure why I am not able to set cookies here. I am using google-chrome and ideally I should have been able to see the cookie there.

Comment: Do you mean to have a cookie that is only valid for 10 seconds?

Comment: Sorry I also tried putting -1 so that's always valid till you close the browser or invalidate session.

Comment: ohh setting it to 999 worked. but -1 should have also worked isn't it?

Comment: No, a negative number would indicate that you want to delete the cookie.

Comment: For reference, 0 would give you a session cookie.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `maxAge` input. Your current code instructs the browser to delete your cookie in 10 seconds.

Gin is wrapping [`http.SetCookie`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#SetCookie) and creating a [`http.Cookie`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie) for you. To better understand what is happening you should read through those two links.

> MaxAge=0 means no 'Max-Age' attribute specified.
>
> MaxAge<0 means delete cookie now, equivalently 'Max-Age: 0'
>
> MaxAge>0 means Max-Age attribute present and given in seconds